# How to save sessions in embedded code across pages

Tags: html, webflow

I was wondering if it is possible to save embedded code sessions on websites, so that when you change page on a website it saves data in the embedded section and transfers it to the next page. I realise I am bad at formulating my question so let me give an example:

I am working in webflow, a website design program that currently doesn't support any user management system.
I have experience with python and with flask and was wondering: If I make a user management system here and use embedded code to show this on my webflow site, can I then do this:
On the page site.com/login I have embedded code that shows the login page of my pythonapp.com/login.
When the user changes to site.com/dashboard, in the embedded form it shows the dashboard hosted on pythonapp.com/dashboard, but of the user that logged in on the previous page. Is it possible to keep a session of embbed code accross multiple pages?

Comment: Why not use python to extract the section of HTML, store it then paste it on the new page.

Comment: check out local storage

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on local storage? Is it in regards to my python app? I am not sure what to look up

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure this is possible, but it probably isn't what you want to do. If you know Python, then why don't you build your web app in Django? You can still design the website in Webflow, but export the html and css to use in your Django web application. For me, this would be the best option.

[Here is Djangos docs on building Views and Templates.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/)